# Reporting services configuration with load balanced front end farm

Tags: reporting-services, application-pool

All,

We're getting lots of reporting services problems with our new site :(

We have a single reporting services box serving reports to 2 web servers. We run app pools on the web servers under NETWORK SERVICE. We've granted the machinename$ account permissions on the reporting services box.

Although we are meant to have session affinity on our load balancer we are getting problems where the report server caches a report for App1$ but is then asked get the cached report for App2$. This then falls over with a "The report execution xxxxxx has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)", although the cached report does exist but under the owner of App1$.

My question is should we change the app pools so they run under an Active Directory account? Therefore they will submit requests to the report server with the same owner.... or is this just bad practice?

Could something else be going on instead? We're investigating the session affinity on the load balancer to see if that is configured incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually we changed the APPPOOLS to run under a centralised AD account and discovered our session affinity was only 5 minutes. Increasing this to 30 mins and the AD account resolved the problem.